# Adding custom domains in a site builder

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm involved in the development of a site builder which is hosted on Google Appengine.

The project is associated to a wildcard domain (e.g. *.foo-bar.com) and we then use the subdomain to determine what site is being requested and dynamically generate the contents based on metadata.

Up until now those domain names were enough. However, we now have clients wishing to associate custom domain with their sites.

The best solution we've come up with is to create a GCE VM which will be running ha_proxy, thus enabling us to redirect their domains to our usual ones. This solution has the obvious disadvantage of adding a new machine to the infrastructure and another service for us to do maintenance on.

We have also considered google's load balancer, but not only would this require us to write additional software, but would also end up costing more every month in fees.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

EDIT:

If, for instance, we want to have www.client1-domain.com redirect to client1.foo-bar.com, we do two things:

(1) ask our client to have his domain point at our ha_proxy

(2) add a new configuration to our ha_proxy such as:

```
acl host_client1 hdr_end(host) -i www.client1-domain.com
use_backend client1_cluster if host_client1

backend client1_cluster
  ...
  server client1 client1.foo-bar.com cookie A check
```

Comment: Please add examples regarding the `we now have clients wishing to associate custom domain with their sites` and the configuration you have tried

Comment: Added an example to the original post further explaining what we [intend to] do.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to fairly easily add lots of [custom domains to an App Engine App](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application). You will need to prove you have access to the domain, and set up a CNAME, but other than that you should be able to do this.